# How can I get the thumbnail/image and desciption of a foreign url, like facebook or twitter?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I want to create an application where users can share link from other websites and a thumbnail/image appear with a little description under it (something like facebook, twitter, reddit..), how can I get to recognize whether the user actually posted a link and automatically generate a thumbnail and an description from that website if it has one

I'm trying to do this with laravel!

Comment: This question has literally nothing to do with Laravel...

Answer (score 1):

You would make an http request to the URL of the other website and use elements from the response to construct the preview. Facebook favors the `og:` meta tags for this purpose. You can do this either in the client or on the server.

If you need to do this live in the browser, I suppose you could use an event handler on the field where the URL might show up, watching it's change event and pattern matching to get a URL. When a URL is detected you fire the routine that makes the http request, gets the remote page and parses specific elements from that page to use to construct your preview.

Answer (score 1):

Big sites like Google, facebook, and twitter can extract [structured data](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/structured_data) from some websites when those sites make it available using something like [schema.org](http://schema.org/), for example. [Schema.org has a github repository](https://github.com/schemaorg/schemaorg) with lots of examples and useful tools for this. You can also take a look at [JSON-LD](http://json-ld.org/)

This is known as [Microdata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microdata_(HTML)) or [RDFa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RDFa). This allows computers to take human readable text on the web and be able to parse them into structured, meaningful information. Like the kind used by Google in search results.

[image: Google Search Structured Data]

There are [some implementations in PHP](https://github.com/alexprut/PHPStructuredData) floating around you can dig up from [packagist](http://packagist.org).

So here's a Microdata example you might find on a site.

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Order">
  <div itemprop="seller" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization">
    <b itemprop="name">ACME Supplies</b>
  </div>
  <div itemprop="customer" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person">
    <b itemprop="name">Jane Doe</b>
  </div>
  <div itemprop="orderedItem" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/OrderItem">
    Item number: <span itemprop="orderItemNumber">abc123</span>
    <span itemprop="orderQuantity">1</span>
    <div itemprop="orderedItem" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
      <span itemprop="name">Widget</span>
    </div>
    <link itemprop="orderItemStatus" href="http://schema.org/OrderDelivered" />Delivered
    <div itemprop="orderDelivery" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ParcelDelivery">
      <time="expectedArrivalFrom">2015-03-10</time>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div itemprop="orderedItem" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/OrderItem">
    Item number: <span itemprop="orderItemNumber">def456</span>
    <span itemprop="orderQuantity">4</span>
    <div itemprop="orderedItem" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
      <span itemprop="name">Widget accessories</span>
    </div>
    <link itemprop="orderItemStatus" href="http://schema.org/OrderInTransit" />Shipped
    <div itemprop="orderDelivery" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ParcelDelivery">
      <time itemprop="expectedArrivalFrom">2015-03-15</time>
      <time itemprop="expectedArrivalUntil">2015-03-18</time>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you hit the url `file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/somepage')` and use a PHP implementation of schema to extract this you can derive the structure of the data for any kind of schema. Things like images, descriptions of articles, questions, people, places, products, etc...

Without this information you're basically just parsing the DOM with something like [DOMDocument](http://php.net/domdocument) in PHP and guessing at what it means. There may be no sensible structure to it at all, but you could look at things like `<title>` tags in HTML, for example to get very basic information.